# Excel VBA: Concatenate lists with differing number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

So, this should be an interesting one...

I have 2 separate reports that provide customer satisfaction information on tickets (if I was able to get the data in 1 list, then this issue would not exist...).  Each list provides information including, most importantly, the ticket number.  One list provides a customer comment, while the other list provides a customer satisfaction score on a 1-5 scale.

A simple concatenate matching ticket numbers would be fairly easy, however, the database designer failed to make the customer comment field mandatory, so approximately 50% of the tickets have no comment.

I have both sheets with the past 60 days of information, however the one with scores is nearly double the size in row number.  What I need to do is combine the lists using first the score sheet, since it will include every ticket, then adding in the comment sheet, matching the comments with their respective tickets.

I am not even sure how to start this code, and I am not looking for finished code, only suggestions on direction.

Pseudo code would be something like:

- Clear useless columns in each sheet
- Sort each sheet by ticket creation date (or ticket number)
- Copy survey comment sheet into survey score sheet, leaving a blank column or two in the middle.
- Assuming that column A and column G include the ticket numbers, sort so that the values match up, and the rows with no survey comment value are blank for column G

Any direction is much appreciated!

Comment: If the Ticket Number is in both Sheets and it is unique then you could use a simple Vlookup to match and bring the data into a single sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the following will do what you want:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find how many rows on Sheet1
LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find how many rows on Sheet2
For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last row
Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet2!R1:R1048576,2,FALSE)"
'enter the Vlookup formula on column number 3, change this number to suit your needs, also change the 2 before FALSE to the column number you wish to bring into Sheet1
Next i
End Sub
```